# SVG: tspan element x attribute not taking absolute position

Tags: svg, tspan

X attribute is absolute X coordinate for the tspan element. But we check the output is taking more pixels.
Instead of tspan element needs to draw from 30 pixels but it is drawn from 39pixes. Why is it like this? My expectation is that it has to draw from 30 pixels
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnlIk.png)

```html
<svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!
    <tspan x="30" y="20"fill="blue">Sub Elemenent Text!</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the problem. It looks like `<tspan>` is at the absolute position. I changed the first letter to be "I" for both elements and x for `<text>` to 10. It looks right to me.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 30">
  <line x1=".2" y1="0" x2=".2" y2="30" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".4"/>
  <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="30" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".4"/>
  <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="30" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".4"/>
  <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="30" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".4"/>
  <text x="10" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!
    <tspan x="30" y="20"fill="blue">I'm Elemenent Text!</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```